Seeking judgement from taghut
I've been reading a piece of work that says that accepting the terms of service in most websites is kufr because they say they can bring you to non Muslim (taghut court's) so by pressing I accept on the terms of service you are agreeing to be judged by a taghut.
I need someone to actually give me answers from the Qur'an and sunnah and not they're own opinions. Also in it he says if theres a dispute with a Muslim in it a kafir cannot be the one who settles it because it is making them a wali which is kufr then he gives an example In soccer saying if they're is a Kaffir referee a Muslim cannot play because or he will be a kafir but if the ref is Muslim it is permissible.
Is this also true??? Iam very anxious about this

https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/402871/ and https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175467/

@UmH if you go to page 100 you will see what I was referring to in the first part of the my question calameo.com/read/006357449cf61b0a10f8c
